# SQL Server stored procedure insert into table from linked server and update another table with max ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, openquery

I have a stored procedure that queries a linked server and performs inserts into a local table. I would like to store the `max(RID)` from the data that I have inserted so that I can use that RID from my tableL as a pointer for my next run.

I cannot use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as I'm not planning to store the identity column of my local but I would like to store `max(RID)` from the linked table.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]

    DECLARE @RID INT 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tableA (RID, Name)
       SELECT * 
       FROM OPENQUERY(linkname, 'SELECT RID, Name FROM linktable WHERE RID > @RID')
END
```

TableA (ID is sequential PK)

```
    | ID | RID | Name |
    |----|-----|------|
```

TableL (ID is sequential PK)

```
    | ID | RID | Time |
    |----|-----|------|
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql#t-using-output-with-an-insert-statement) to capture the RIDs that you're inserting and then persist the `max(RID)` somewhere. Also, based on your logic, probably `<=` should be `>` if you want new rows since the last execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I realized after posting this that you can't pass variables into `OPENQUERY`, so I changed it to just be a direct query. Depending on your usage, this may or may not be okay.

I'm personally a fan of temp tables, so I would probably do something like this:

```sql
-- Get the RID of the last successful run for this table
DECLARE @LastRID int = 0;
SELECT @LastRID = LastRID
FROM dbo.SomeETLTrackingTable
WHERE TableName = 'linktable';

-- Pull the data from linkname over to this server
SELECT RID, [Name]
INTO #data
FROM linkname.linkdb.dbo.linktable
WHERE RID > @LastRID;

-- Insert the data we pulled
INSERT INTO tableA ([Name])
SELECT [Name]
FROM #data;

-- Get the max RID of the batch
SELECT @LastRID = MAX(RID)
FROM #data;

-- Update our ETL tracking table
UPDATE e SET e.LastRID = @LastRID
FROM dbo.SomeETLTrackingTable e
WHERE e.TableName = 'linktable';
```

Note: I'm not including any transactions or error handling, but you should to ensure you only update the tracking table upon successful import.

---

I would also suggest you learn other methods for ETL'ing data. I'm not going to say that what you're doing is wrong, because it works perfectly fine for many applications. But if you are trying to do more complex ETL processes in the future, it would be beneficial to learn what other options you have.

I'm only going to name a couple because there are TONS of things out there:

- `rowversion` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql
- Change Tracking - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server

Comment: Thanks , this helps . Can you suggest on any error handling ok how it can be done before I update the other table

Comment: @RData glad it helped. If you feel this answered your question, make sure to mark it as the answer. As far as error handling goes, that's too much to answer in a comment, I would suggest joining the SQL Server community slack channel and reddit channels to ask for help on that (brentozar.com/slack)

Comment: done and thanks for suggestion . One last question : if any of the statements (Insert or Update) in the above procedure fail , does that stop the SP from executing any of the statements ? my concern is that i do not want to update if any of my inserts fail

Comment: @RData wherever it fails, that's what gets done. So if you have an insert then an update, and the update fails, then the insert would still go though. To avoid this, you would use transactions. So that if anything fails to run, it can rollback any pending changes. But this would definitely be a good one to ask on the slack channel. It's much more casual there, so you can ask for help and they'll be happy to walk you through it.